# Notice: Undefined index: While using <select>

Tags: php, post

Ok so here's the code

PHP:

```
 $rgen        = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['gender']));

 $dobm        = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['dobm']));
 $dobd        = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['dobd']));
 $doby        = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['doby']));
 $dab         = $doby.$dobm.$dobd;


 $tos         = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['TOS']));
```

HTML:

```
    <select id=ftxti name=gender style="width:130px; padding: 10px 15px; height: 52px;" >
        <option disabled selected >I'am</option>
        <option value=0 >Male</option>
        <option value=1 >Female</option>
    </select>

    <td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class=dob >

    <select name="dobm" id=ftxti style="width:103px;" >
        <option disabled selected >Month</option>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>

    <select name="dobd" id=ftxti style="width:95px;" >
        <option disabled selected >Day</option>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>

    <select name="doby" id=year style="width:95px;" >
        <option disabled selected >Year</option>
            <?php for ($i = 1980; $i < date('Y'); $i++) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>

<label >
    <div id=tosag >
        <input type=checkbox name=TOS value=1 />
        <font style="font-size: 11px;" >
          I agree to <a href=# style="color: rgb(50, 92, 129);">TOS</a>
        </font>
    </div>
</label>
```

And The Errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: dobm in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined index: dobd in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: doby in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: TOS in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 36

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 101

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 109

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 118

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc\e.conf\sys.proc\proc.reg\use.register.php on line 126
```

Any help would be appreciated. Problem is i seem to have defined the index but i must be missing a rule here, I'm kind of rusty at PHP so please be gentle with me, And I'm also new here so if i do anything wrong I'm sorry...

Comment: var_dump($_POST), and you'll see what's there. Plus you are using deprecated mysql_* functions and probably have an error while connecting to mysql.

Comment: I bet you're not checking to see if the form is submitted before accessing `$_POST`

Comment: Well the form is submited before i set the variables.
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

     //set form variables

Comment: Try putting `name=TOS` in quotes as in `name="TOS"`. Plus, you have many others that do not have them, it's always good practice to keep uniformity.

Comment: Also, if you're using a class for your DB connection and the variables are outside of it (not in the scope), and/or no global(s) set, then that risks at being the root of your problem.

Comment: Ohh;  see i use to have a habbit of quoting all of my responses in quotes I've just been away from it in a while

Comment: Ok so there are there new problems, Here's the full site, I've finished login system (50% without the msql input). but the registeration system is being a pain 

<a href="http://ewotty.cu.cc/" /> http://ewotty.cu.cc/register </a>

Comment: Your DB credentials are obviously wrong or improperly setup. Make sure also that you're not mixing `MySQL_` with `MySQLi_`

Comment: @Fred-ii- One sec im fixing it, it's not that' The DB connection errors are due to the fact that i've just now uploaed the files from my localhost server and i need to change them to fit my domain. but one second, please check back in like 20 minutes tops.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all the code, it is tough to guess... but I would check first and make sure your form method is set to post.

Comment: It is 

<form method=post action='' >

then i have my inputs then i close the form.

Answer (score 1):

I thought both Html an Php are in same page. At the time of HTML Page loading without submit the form, all the PHP variables are empty. thats y it shows like that. You need to write in this way.

```
  if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
  $rgen = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['gender']));
  }
```

Another way, If you want to hide the notices & warnings, you can add the below code at the top of the page. I won't suggest this in Development Environment.

```
   error_reporting(0);
     (or) 
   ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
```

Comment: Yeah i thought i might need an "if" statement but i wasn't sure if i was missing anything. THANKS MAN! I'll see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't fix anything... but you probably meant for `<td>` to be `</td>`

```
    <select id=ftxti name=gender style="width:130px; padding: 10px 15px; height: 52px;" >
        <option disabled selected >I'am</option>
        <option value=0 >Male</option>
        <option value=1 >Female</option>
    </select>

    <td>   <----- This should probably be a closing tag!
</tr>
```

You also should really add quotes around your attributes:

```
<a href=#  should be <a href="#"

or

id=ftxti should be id="ftxti"

or

<option value=1 > should be <option value="1" >
```